# Receivng error "Invalid property 'xxx' of bean class" when trying to submit form via JSTL form tags

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to build a simple Spring project where a user can search the database via form. It works perfectly if I use a regular form input, but if I try to use JSTL form tags it breaks. Any help would be appreciated

JSP:

```
<form:form action="/search" method="post" modelAttribute="music">
        <form:label path="artist">Artist</form:label>
        <form:errors path="artist"/>
        <form:input path="artist"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String search(@RequestParam(value="artist") String search, Model model) {
        List<Music> results = musicService.findArtist(search);
        model.addAttribute("search", search);
        model.addAttribute("results", results);
        return "music/search.jsp";
    }
```

Service:

```
    public List<Music> findArtist(String search){
        return musicRepository.findByArtistContaining(search);
    }
```

repo:

```
List<Music> findByArtistContaining(String search);
```

Really not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm sure I'm messing up the JSP code somehow. I just want to pull the results from the DB via the repo method findByArtistContaining

error I'm receiving when trying to access is:

```
Invalid property 'artist' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'artist' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Comment: Have you created Any model class called music?
If yes, Have you define `artist` property inside it and also generate the getter setter methods for that? And verify also if there are any typo mistakes too.

Comment: Yep!  have the artist declared and the getter and setter as getArtist(), setArtist(). When I have a regular HTML input named the same, the search works perfectly. Thanks for taking a look, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry late to the party, but I think this wouldn't work as the request param doesn't match the name of the String your trying to map it to, as stated here;

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

So changing to below should work;

```
@RequestParam(name="artist") String artist,
```

Comment: Super appreciate that, I forgot to update but got it all figured out and that's exactly what was going on. Thank you!